# Struggling with fstab

Tags: root, fstab, plex

I'm really struggling to understand my fstab file, I would like to mount the nfs so that all users can edit the directories (rw) but I seem to get 'root:root'.

My fstab file:

```
192.168.1.74:/volume1/Barry/Plex/tv  /mnt/plex/media/tv  nfs  nofail defaults 0  0
```

Comment: Wrong fstab line, options have to be separated by comma, not space. `nofail defaults` is wrong, it has to be `nofail,defaults` .

Comment: Like this? 192.168.1.74:/volume1/Barry/Plex/tv  /mnt/plex/media/tv  nfs  nofail, defaults, user, 0  0   when I do mount -a I get this mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 15 -- ignored

Comment: No, no spaces, options are separated by commas, without any spaces, see my example above.

Comment: That worked thank you. Unfortunately didn't fix the issue I was having though :(

Comment: Please fix that in your question via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1477095/edit) too. I'm not a networking guru, so with your initial problem you'll have to wait for someone else to help you.

Comment: Thats fine I appreciate all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

nfs permissions are (mostly) controlled by the server, not the client.

So you have to change permissions on the server, not change the mount on the client.

Although, you need to get the mount right on the client first before you can access anything.  As stated in the comments, your fstab line is wrong.  A correct fstab line has exactly 6 fields, separated by whitespace.  You have 7 fields there, as the 4th field (options) is split and should have a comma instead of whitespace separating the options.